# In Shiny R render html conditionally based on user selection

Tags: html, r, shiny, server-side-rendering, reactive

I want to show different html files based on user input. Basically user makes his selection in two **pickerinput** elements and based on the selection a different html file is shown.

I have in my **ui. R**

```
  fluidRow( style = "background-color:#FFFAFA00;",
       
            htmlOutput("example")
  ))),
```

and in my **server. R**

example <- reactive({

```
if (input$chap == "ai" & input$cat == "ch") {
  htmlOutput("aich")
} 

else if (input$chap == "ai" & input$cat == "pr") {
  htmlOutput("aipr")
  }
})
```

Nothing happens when selected. Any ideas on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try this:

```
observe({
  
  if (input$chap == "ai" & input$cat == "ch") {
    output$example <- renderText("html_code_here")
  } 
  
  else if (input$chap == "ai" & input$cat == "pr") {
    output$example <- renderText("html_code_here")
  }
})
```

Also, `observeEvent(c(input$chap, input$chap), {...})` can work i think.

It is hard to tell with the information provided if this will work, but I built an example.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(textInput(inputId = 'chap','input 1',placeholder = 'ai'),
               textInput(inputId = 'cat', 'input 2',placeholder = 'ch')),
  mainPanel(htmlOutput('example')))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    req(input$chap)
    
    if (input$chap == "ai" & input$cat == "ch") {
      output$example <- renderText("<h1>This is the H1</h1>")
    } 
    
    else { if (input$chap == "ai" & input$cat == "pr") {
      output$example <- renderText("aipr")
    }
    }  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]